# MemoryCache Aspnet MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memorycache

i've a problem for implement a MemoryCache object in aspnet.
This is my code

```
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(10.0);
        cache.Add("keyName", resultQuery, policy);
```

The object is correct insert in the cache but when i delete and rewrite it the new object in the view is visible only in my session.

```
        var q = queryObject;
        var cacheKey = "keyName";
        MemoryCache.Default.Remove(cacheKey);
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(10.0);
        cache.Add(cacheKey, q, policy);
```

And this is the simple Get Implementation.

```
        cache.Get(cacheKey);
```

I don't understand why sometimes works in different browser session and sometimes doesn't work.
Someone can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean _only visible only in my session_? and what make you think that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the System.Web.Caching.cache
Use this code to get Cache

public string[] GetCache()
{

```
string[] cache = Cache["names"] as string[];
if(names == null)
{
cache= DB.GetCache();
Cache["names"] = cache;
}
return cache;
```

}